# Converting slider values from points to kg

Tags: javascript, css, math

I am working on a coworkers code and trying to understand the math here.

I have a slider with the values of `0-120` to define weight values that will be transformed into `kilograms` based on the position of the slider (the 0-120 value). It's the `sx` variable

First, we assume the following values:

```
0 on slider => 88 lbs => 39.9 kg

146.19469026548674 on slider => 300 lbs => 136.078 kg

1kg is 2.2lbs
```

**What i need is to take the sx variable and convert that into a kg.** 
Anything below `88` pounds gets 0 and anything above `300` pounds gets 120 as the sx value

**UPDATE**

If i use the value from the database, which is stored as kg how do i convert it to `sx` this is what ive done so far:

```
sx = (weightVal-40)*1.25;
```

Where `weightVal` is the kg val from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you need:

kg = 39.9 - sx * (136.078 - 39.9) / 120

In detail:

Slider Range (sx): 0 - 120

Weight Range (wlb): 88 - 300

Weight Range (wkg): 39.9 - 136.078

Conversion Factor kg -> lbs: 1 kg = 2.20462 lbs

Convert Slider (sx) to Weight kgs (wkg):
* Assume sx is limited to values between 0 and 120
* if sx = 0 then wkg = 39.9
* if sx = 120 then wkg = 136.078
* otherwise wkg = 39.9 + sx * (136.078 - 39.9) / 120
    the weight in kgs (wkg) is equal to the bottom value of the slider (0) plus the proportion of the total range (136.078 - 39.9) of the slider as indicated by the slider position (sx).

Convert Weight kgs (wkg) to Slider Position (sx):
* sx must be within range 0 - 120
* if wkg < 39.9 then sx = 0
* if wkg > 136.078 then sx = 120
* otherwise sx = ((wkg - 39.9) / (136.078 - 39.9)) * 120
    the slider position (sx) is to equal to the amount the weight is greater than the bottom value (wkg - 39.9) as a proportion of the total weight range represented by the slider (136.078 - 39.9) converted to the slider position range (120).

Convert Slider (sx) to Weight lbs (wlb):
* Assume sx is limited to values between 0 and 120
* if sx = 0 then wlb = 88
* if sx = 120 then wlb = 300
* otherwise wlb = 88 + sx * (300 - 88) / 120
    the weight in lbs (wlb) is equal to the bottom value of the slider (0) plus the proportion of the total range (300 - 88) of the slider as indicated by the slider position (sx).

Convert Weight lbs (wlb) to Slider Position (sx):
* sx must be within range 0 - 120
* if wlb < 88 then sx = 0
* if wlb > 300 then sx = 120
* otherwise sx = ((wlb - 88) / (300 - 88)) * 120
    the slider position (sx) is to equal to the amount the weight is greater than the bottom value (wlb - 88) as a proportion of the total weight range represented by the slider (300 - 88) converted to the slider position range (120).

Or you can calculate in pounds and convert to kgs using the conversion above.

Care is just needed then to ensure that you do not encounter truncation or overflow errors converting between floating point, signed int and unsigned int values.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I imagine its simple math im figuring it out now but i want to compare

Comment: OK. The structure of the calculation is correct, you just have some slight variations in the values.

So I would use

sx = (weightVal - 39.9) * 120 / (136.078 - 39.9)

Then add boundary checks in the code with this to handle weightVal < 39.9 and > 136.078.

Comment: Can you show me how to go from kg to sx also. then i will say correct answer

Comment: it goes from 87 to -124lbs as i scroll to the right. my lbs algorithm is: `var lbs = Math.ceil(parseInt(2.20462*kg));` also can you explain the calculations

Comment: First the bottom value of 87. This is being caused by the parseInt call: 39.9 kg * 2.20462 = 87.964338. parseInt returns 87 so Math.ceil returns 87.

Documentation recommends setting the radix with parseInt as well. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: Im not following what you are saying. Can you please update the answer to show sx to kg conversion and kg to sx conversion

Comment: Also Math.ceil does not need to be passed an int. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)
So this will correct the bottom slider value: var lbs = Math.ceil(2.20462*kg);

Comment: you used pounds instead of kg